# IOS: How to get message body, subject and recepient after message is sent via MFMailComposeController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I am sending email via following method:

```
-(void) sendEmailOpenControllerWithSubject:(NSString *)subject messsageBody:(NSString *) message
{
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:subject];
    [controller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
    [controller setToRecipients:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:currentProspect.email, nil]];
    if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I am setting message body subject and recipient but it is likely that user changes these attribute in MailComposer.

**What I need:**

So I want to get the contents like message body,subject and recipients after the email is sent. As it is possible that user has changed these via mail composer.

Comment: I am quite sure that this is not possible. This has already been discussed here at SO, but I do not have the reference at this moment.

Comment: Its a security issue too - user types some private message, the app can see what it was, send it via a network channel to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in iOS 5, you can register to be notified of changes to the availability of text message sending.

```
A userInfo dictionary key for the MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityDidChangeNotification

NSString *const MFMessageComposeViewControllerTextMessageAvailabilityKey;
```

Refer more  on Message UI Framework  [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2FDocumentation%2FMessageUI%2FReference%2FMessageUI_Framework_Reference%2FMessageUI_Framework_Reference.pdf&ei=W51lUPSvM8WqrAfhwoHQCQ&usg=AFQjCNFf675WGr7DDeMV-oLNk7nz9fZxAg)

Comment: The question was about sending e-mail (MFMailComposeViewController), not about sending SMS/text messages (MFMessageComposeViewController)