# How to get the sent emails in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, email, ios7

I have a requirement that I have to send an email and show them in sent items. Using iOS mail API. I can send the email. But I am not able to retrieve the sent items.

Is there any possible way to store the sent email and show them in sent items with all the details like ( to, message body,...) ?

Is it possible to fetch any information from `MFMailComposeViewController` in the delegate methods?

```
­-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:

(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    // Any way to fetch sent mail info
}
```

Comment: Not possible. This question was discussed [here][1] already.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639990/ios-how-to-get-message-body-subject-and-recepient-after-message-is-sent-via-mf

Answer (score 0):

You can set `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` in your code. This delegate has a method

```
- mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:
```

which sends the results enum through which you can figure out if the mail was sent or not. Then you can save your email message/subject and show the user list of emails they have sent.